# How to redirect to subdirectory using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I do not understand `htaccess` fully so I need help solving this. I need to redirect users from the directory `www.example.com/es` and `www.example.com/en` to the subdirectory `www.example.com/old/es` and `www.example.com/old/en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(en|es)(/.*)?$ /old/$1$2
```

If you only want to redirect `/en` and `/es`, and not `/en/foo` or `/es/something/else` then remove the `$2` bit from the end.